# React Native - Disabled scroll parent FlatList and Enabled scroll child FlatList

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, react-flatlist

I need to disable the scrolling from the parent `FlatList` (the scroll will be implemented by pressing the button) and activate the scroll from the child `FlatList`. Due to the fact that I set `scrollEnabled={false}` for the parent `FlatList`, the scrolling does not work for the child `Flatlist`. How to solve this problem?

```js
const data = [
    { type: 'list', data: ['Apple', 'Banna', 'Pear', 'Orange', 'Grape', 'Pineapple']},
    { type: 'list', data: ['Bike', 'Car', 'Train', 'Plane', 'Boat', 'Rocket']}
];

return (
  <FlatList
    data={data}
    keyExtractor={item => item.id}
    renderItem={({item}) => {
        return <FlatList
          data={item.data}
          keyExtractor={item => item.id}
          numColumns={item.data.length} // horizontal
          renderItem={({item}) => (
            <View style={{width: width, height: 50, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
                <Text>{item}</Text>
            </View>
          )
          }
          pagingEnabled
        />
    }}
    horizontal
    pagingEnabled
    scrollEnabled={false}
  />
);
```

[Example Code Snack](https://snack.expo.dev/6IQygseQg)

Comment: specify what is the end result you want or some reference

Comment: @AshwithSaldanha I need the scrolling to work for the child `Flatlist` and at the same time off for the parent `Flatlist`